# How do I setup my server with https and perl Dancer as a standalone server?

Tags: perl, ssl, twitter, dancer

We need to create a quick demo of a web service using Perl's Dancer as a standalone webserver, and Twitter API.

Unforunately, [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) only allows https/ssl requests but I have no idea how to set this up on a server that isn't using Apache.

I have a [Comodo EV Cert](http://ssl.comodo.com/ev-ssl-certificates.php), and I think a correct pem file in the /etc/ssl/localcerts directory on my server.

I also have [Dancer::Plugin::RequireSSL](http://search.cpan.org/~hobbestig/Dancer-Plugin-RequireSSL-0.121331/lib/Dancer/Plugin/RequireSSL.pm) and [Crypt::SSLeay](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Crypt-SSLeay/SSLeay.pm) installed but the instructions aren't clear to me.

Do I add it to the project/bin/app.pl file?

Do I need to add environment variables to bash?

How do I configure [Dancer to use https](http://search.cpan.org/~hobbestig/Dancer-Plugin-RequireSSL-0.121331/lib/Dancer/Plugin/RequireSSL.pm) for making calls to Twitter API using [Net::Twitter](http://search.cpan.org/~mmims/Net-Twitter-4.01003/lib/Net/Twitter.pod)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the cert is set to the environment with Crypt::SSLeay [stated here](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Crypt-SSLeay/SSLeay.pm#CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_SUPPORT).

It also looks like Dancer can be [configured](http://search.cpan.org/~hobbestig/Dancer-Plugin-RequireSSL-0.121331/lib/Dancer/Plugin/RequireSSL.pm#CONFIGURATION) to redirect to ssl in a config file.

Take a look at [Support](http://search.cpan.org/~hobbestig/Dancer-Plugin-RequireSSL-0.121331/lib/Dancer/Plugin/RequireSSL.pm#SUPPORT) for the comment about supporting HTTPS in Dancer.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all, why is it accepted?